# what happens to a scala map when it is updated and assigned to a var?

Tags: scala, maps, immutability, var, mutable

Day 3 of learning Scala.

I guess maps are immutable. I was wondering, when we update an immutable map and assign it to a new var, what happens to the old map? Is the memory just immediately freed up?

Also, when the new map is assigned to a var which by definition is mutable, what does this mean? Because a map by default, even the new map is not mutable.

Does anyone know the answers? Is there a good resource that can explain these things to me? ( what happens under the hood etc )

Comment: Generally, I would recommend [Daniel Spiewak's talk](https://vimeo.com/28760673) on functional data structures.

Answer (score 3):

*"what happens to the old map?"*

It depends on whether anyone else is using it. If not, the memory it uses will be freed at some point by a process called "garbage collection". There is no way for the program to tell when this actually happens.

*"what does [it mean] when a new map is assigned to a var"*

`val` and `var` both define a "variable" that refers to an object. The difference is that a `val` always points to the same object but a `var` may be updated to point to a different object.

In contrast, `mutable` and `immutable` are properties of *an object itself*. An `immutable` object will always have the same value whereas the value of a `mutable` object can be changed.

Comment: It may also be the case that the newly constructed map smartly shares some internal structures with the old map, in which case the old map is, of course, not garbage collected.